# Entity Framework: is there a complete list of supported IQueryable extension methods?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm looking for this list for Entity Framework. Ideally, I'd like to have a list of other supported methods (or members - e.g. constructors), e.g. for DateTime type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550%28VS.100%29.aspx). See also [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681%28VS.100%29.aspx).