# LINQ to SQL: is there a complete list of supported IQueryable extension methods?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for such list for LINQ to SQL. Ideally, I'd like to have a list of other supported methods (or members - e.g. constructors), e.g. for DateTime type.

Comment: The people who are voting to close as an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875156/ are **wrong.** The rules for L2S and L2E are different, as is the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342%28VS.100%29.aspx), although less complete than for L2E. See also [Data Types and Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx). This includes `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: I accepted the reply, since it seems this is the most comprehensive information that can be found. There is no list of supported \ unsupported IQueryable methods - there are just (some?) examples of unsupported ones: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882656.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337580.aspx . All those extension methods are documented as members of IQueryable.

Rembmer that IQueryable implements IEnumerable, so anything that IEnumerable implements is also available on IQueryable, with the caveat that **some of those methods don't work!** In particular, anything that uses a custom comparator will compile correctly, but will get a run-time error from LINQ to SQL. Also true for .Take() and .Skip() with non-numeric values.

Comment: I fully aware about IQueryable and IEnumerable (I'm one of developers of ORM tool supporting LINQ). Your reply isn't helpful, because only a subset of IQueryable methods is supported by *any* LINQ provider. The question itself indicates I know a complete list of these methods...

Comment: Then your question certainly isn't clear. Why would DateTime be handled differently from any other value type? What constructors (of any type) would be supported by IQueryable, which is an interface? What other methods would Iqueryable support, other than those defined on it or on the interfaces it inherits from?

Comment: Yes, may be the question is really unclear, especially if you don't devote yourselves to LINQ translation too much. Supported constructors & members of other types are interesting because IQueryable provider either supports a particular one of them or not. "Supports" means it is able to translate an expression with this member to its SQL equivalent. Obviously, not anything can be translated by this way, thus a set of BCL types \ members supported by a particular provider is interesting as well.